# where to find full source code of application with RPC calls to test

Tags: vaadin, rpc, vaadin7

as I'm trying to implement some RPC on my own vaadin application, and having some problems with it, I've been looking around for tutorials with full source code to import into STS and run, but alas I haven't found any. I mean, there is plenty of tutorials, but no source code. Even on the vaadin website itself, here http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#foundation/rpc, there is an interesting tutorial but when you check the source code, there is an awful lot of stuff missing. DOes anybody know where I could find a simple, basic application source code so I can run it and understand a bit more about it?

Comment: Why do you wish to do RPC? With vaadin you don't hove to fiddle with RPC. The RPC used has some security builtin...

Comment: Because going forward I'll have to use RPC on a regular basis to get the client side to talk to java. Doesn't matter whether it's a good thing or not or not efficient, that's what I will have to do, so I'm just trying to get to grips with it : - )

Comment: The whole source can be found on GitHub https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin . But usually you write your own JS components on top of the Vaadin stack as documented here: https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/clientsidewidgets/clientsidewidgets-overview.html or/and https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-overview.html

Comment: thanks, that project seems to be pretty big, do you think it's a good idea to import it as it is?

Comment: I'm not sure what you wish to do with it, but it's for you to descide if it's a good idea or not.